# Excel xlDown selects two blocks of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following dataset

```
100  
100  


200  
200  


300  


400
```

I am using this code

```
    Dim rngToSum As Range
    Dim TopCell As Range
    Dim BottomCell As Range

    Set rngToSum = Intersect(Selection.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    Set TopCell = rngToSum.Cells(1, 1)

    If TopCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Set TopCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
    End If

    Do
        Set BottomCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
        BottomCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=sum(" & Range(TopCell, BottomCell).Address & ")"
        Set TopCell = BottomCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)
    Loop Until Intersect(rngToSum, TopCell) Is Nothing

End Sub
```

It sums up the data where there are 2 rows (e.g. 100 and 100) but rather than returning 300 after 300 and 400 after 400 it return 700 after 400 as it selects them both for summing. I know this is to do with the 3rd from the bottom line 'End(xlDown)' but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check to see if the range you're going to sum has a blank cell in it.  If so, then one could say it's a single cell, so don't set the BottomCell to be `.End(xlDown)`.  In that case, it'd be the same cell as `TopCell`.

I've taken a slightly different approach, but the idea is the same.  It'll go from `A1` to the last Row in Column A:

```
Sub sum_blocks()
Dim singleRow As Boolean
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Dim i As Long
Dim rngToSum As Range
Dim topCell As Range, bottomCell As Range

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    singleRow = False
    Set topCell = Cells(i, 1)
    Set bottomCell = topCell.End(xlDown)
    Range(topCell, bottomCell).Select
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(topCell, bottomCell)) <> Range(topCell, bottomCell).Cells.Count Then
        singleRow = True
        Set bottomCell = topCell
    End If
    Set rngToSum = Range(topCell, bottomCell)
    rngToSum.Select
    bottomCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & rngToSum.Address & ")"
    bottomCell.Offset(1, 0).Font.Bold = True
    bottomCell.Offset(1, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
    If singleRow Then
        i = bottomCell.Row + 1
    Else
        i = bottomCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - 1 ' bottomCell.Row + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this the only issue is (not mentioned in the OP) is that sometimes there are two blank rows between each block of data and this code breaks down when that happens. Is there a way to account for that? Thanks.

Comment: @Naz - See edit.